# How to set up ng-file-upload in laravel-angular project?

Tags: angularjs, module, laravel-5, ng-file-upload

I am using laravel-angular set up. http://www.laravel-angular.io/#/

I am also trying to use ng-file-upload as described here. https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

I am having trouble set up my project to access this ngFileUpload directive, it says in the installation.( https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#-install)

```
<script src="angular(.min).js"></script>
<script src="ng-file-upload-shim(.min).js"></script> <!-- for no html5 browsers support -->
<script src="ng-file-upload(.min).js"></script>
```

but my question is where to I put these references if I am using elixir to compile all my dependencies?

Also where can I put this line if I need to load it into the app (I was thinking index.modules.js)

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);
```

Have installed and used a few plugins for this project before, but this one is giving me trouble.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I keep getting errors when the app starts running, before I need to inject "Upload" into the controller.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: If it's not giving any error, just inject `Upload` in your controller and use it.

Comment: i get an error before that point that it cannot find the necessary scripts, will edit question with more explination.

Answer (score 3):

I found a work around, basically need to inject $scope into the controller and define fileChanged() function as follows.

```
class TestController{
    constructor($scope,API){
        'ngInject';
        this.API = API
        this.$scope = $scope;
    }

    $onInit(){
        this.file = null;
        this.$scope.fileChanged = function(elm) {
            console.log('hey')
            this.file = elm.file;
            this.$apply();
        }
    }
    upload() {
        console.log(this.file)
    }

}
```

can now call in HTML template like so:

```
<input type="file"
               accept="image/*"
               ng-model="vm.file"
               onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileChanged(this); angular.element(this).scope().$digest();" />
```

I do not fully understand how this works, but it seems to be calling my function now, so should be able to get it working. The following 2 links were extremely helpful.

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-file-uploads

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1375

Comment: this means no longer using prebuild directive, I will building my own that is ore compliant with laravel-angular way of doing things

Comment: this works by setting `vm.file` outside of angular (`onchange` is not angular event) and then forcing a recompile of the angular component to recognize the updated `vm.file`